# Wordpress comment form in Drupal?

Tags: comments

Wordpress comment form contains a text field where visitors can enter a link to their website. Is there any module ( or simple way )to achieve the same thing in Drupal ?

What I'm really looking for is a solution that:

- adds a new field to the comment form that needs to be validated as a link
- when the comment is displayed , the username needs to link to the website entered in the form , not to the user profile as it does by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [URL field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/url) to create the website field on the comment entity. You can then use [function theme_comment_submitted](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/theme_comment_submitted/6) in your theme's preprocess functions to override the `$submitted` variable that is used in `comment.tpl.php` from the Drupal root folder `/modules/comment/` (you can also copy this file into your theme's templates folder for further customization of the comment display).

The idea would be to alter `function theme_comment_submitted` (shown below) to include the username hyperlinked with an `href` provided by your URL field.

```
function theme_comment_submitted($comment) {
  return t('Submitted by !username on @datetime.', array(
    '!username' => theme('username', $comment),
    '@datetime' => format_date($comment->timestamp),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very simple. You can add fields to the comment entity.
Have a look at these explanations of how o achieve this:

http://kps3.com/thots/adding-new-fields-to-comments-in-drupal-7

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entities/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the question was not really well formulated so I added some more detail.